# GooglePlay Billing lifecycle

Tags: in-app-billing, android-billing, google-play-developer-api, play-billing-library

I'm trying to use the latest in app billing library of [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2) but I have doubt about its lifecycle `onConsumeFinished` is called before or after `onPurchasesUpdated`?

When I should release resources?

Should I update status in `onPurchasesUpdated` or I have to use `onActivityResult` after the user have purchased an item from the Google Play purchase dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about the lifecycle [is all here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html).

When to update status depends on your design. Remember that purchases might change status outside your app's flow (for example if the user gets a refund) and also that your app might be killed (eg if the device gets low on memory after the user switches to another app) so you need to handle purchase status correctly both on App startup and during the normal purchase flow.